# Rendering images from MySQL database

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I have the following controller method to show image on the JSP page based on member id:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/artists/members/photo/{memberId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void renderPhoto(
HttpServletResponse response,
@PathVariable("memberId") Integer memberId)
throws IOException {

   Member member = memberService.loadMember(memberId);
   byte[] photo = member.getPhoto();

   response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
   response.setContentLength(photo.length);
   response.getOutputStream().write(photo);
   response.getOutputStream().flush();

}
```

For each member I want to show his image:

```
<c:forEach items="${members}" var="member">
    <img src="${ctx}/artists/members/photo/<c:out value='${member.memberId}' />"></img>
</c:forEach>
```

But instead, the broken link image is showed in the browser. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't really use spring, but I don't see where ${members} is set up. What HTML is being generated?

Comment: ${members} is injected into the session using another controller's method, and it's correctly populated and accessed from the JSP. This is the generated HTML: <img src=/artists/memebers/photo/1></img>, where "1" is member id.